# Exception in reading an MP3 file through AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to read an MP3 file through class javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem but I am getting an `UnsupportedAudioFileException`. 
My code trying to read the audio file looks like:-

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

I am getting the following exception:-

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
```

Does AudioSystem class not support mp3 format? If not then what formats does it supports? Or Am I doing some mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't support MP3 (hence the `UnsupportedAudioFileException`). The supported files are quite basic (WAV and that sort of thing), so for any advanced codecs you'll need separate libraries.

Comment: Is there any way to read mp3 format file through Java without using thirdparty library?

Comment: Only if you write a library yourself.

Comment: @VineetTyagi Look at something like [mp3spi](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html)

Comment: @greg-449 It seems to be useful. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: See the [info. page for Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for both the cause of this problem and the fix (using the `mp3plugin.jar`)..